# How to instantiate a new Windows Form with Quartz.NET without problems?

Tags: c#, winforms, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.NET library to create a job in my C# application.

I have some registers in my database, so I have a table which contains a column called "start_date". The job runs every 50 seconds, so I compare the dates from the column "start_date" with the date of my computer, and if the dates are equal, I want to instantiate a new Windows Form with a message and a button.

At the moment, the new Windows Form is opening at the right moment, but the message is not showed and the window stops to respond.

Basically, in my code I have something like this:

**FormMessage.cs**

```
public partial class FormMessage : Form
{
    public FormMessage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public FormMessage(double minutes)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string message = string.Format("You have {0} minutes!", minutes);
        lblMessage.Text = message ;
    }

    private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**JobMessage.cs**

```
public class JobMessage: IJob
{
    List<Information> informations;

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //Class with methods to get registers from database.
        InformationAPI infoAPI = new InformationAPI();

        informations = infoAPI.GetInformations();

        foreach (Information info in informations)
        {
            DateTime computerDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime infoDateTime = info.StartDate;
            double difference;

            if (DateTime.Compare(computerDateTime, infoDateTime) < 0)
            {
                difference = Math.Round(infoDateTime.Subtract(computerDateTime).TotalMinutes);

                if (difference == 5)
                {
                    FormMessage formMessage = new FormMessage(difference);
                    formMessage.Show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Someone have some idea of the reason why the FormMessage window stops to respond?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: get rid of the Initialize in the `FormMessage() { }` make it an empty constructor. Change the `formMessage.Show()' to use the `.ShowModal()` method, create an auto property for the message variable and assign it once inside of the FormMessage(difference) Constructor, or pass a default string.Empty parameter to that constructor and use / take advantage of the `this.` construct more important.. use namespace as well ..let us know if any of these recommendations work for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the attention. I think you meant `.showDialog()`, am I right? Because just changing the `formMessage.Show()` to `formMessage.showDialog()` the application is running well! Thank you very much. I read the documentation, but didn't understand very well, can you explain the difference between the methods, please?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I meant.. and you're welcome for the help glad I was able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

You can try Quartz Listeners to let them open the form to show the data and keep the execution out of the job scope:

```
Action<IJobExecutionContext, JobExecutionException> listenerAction = (c, e) => {
    var dataMap = context.GetJobDetail().GetJobDataMap();
    var difference = dataMap.GetIntValue("difference");

    FormMessage formMessage = new FormMessage(difference);
    formMessage.Show();
}

var listener = new SyncJobListener(listenerAction);
```

And add the listener in to the scheduler:

```
scheduler.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(listener, 
    GroupMatcher<JobKey>.GroupEquals("GroupName"));
```

Using this `SyncJobListener`:

```
public class SyncJobListener : IJobListener
{
    private readonly Action<IJobExecutionContext, JobExecutionException> _syncExecuted;

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public SyncJobListener(
        Action<IJobExecutionContext, JobExecutionException> syncExecuted
        )
    {
        Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        _syncExecuted = syncExecuted;
    }

    public void JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
    }

    public void JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
    }

    public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
    {
        _syncExecuted(context, jobException);
    }
}
```

I have not tested this so if the `dataMap` does not have any data, you are going to need to allow the persistance:

```
[PersistJobDataAfterExecution]
[DisallowConcurrentExecution]
public class JobMessage: IJob {}
```

Comment: I will try this solution. Thanks for your help!